# Why is $u(x,y)$ "independent" of $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

From Wikipedia:

> A relatively simple PDE is:
>
> $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=0$$
>
> This relation implies that the function $u(x,y)$ is independent of $x$.

Why is that last line true? Whenever I read anything in the form of $f(x)$ I immediately think "the function $f$, **which depends on $x$**, is..." So what do they mean when they say $u(x,y)$ is independent of $x$? Where is my thinking flawed?

Comment: They mean that $u(x,y)$, as a function of $x$; is constant. That is, $u(x,y)=u(x',y)$ for any choice of $x,x'$.

Comment: Integrate the PDE w.r.t $x$ to give: $u(x,y) = h(y) + \textrm{constant}$. Thus it is independent of $x$. So really one could rephrase this PDE as an ODE of the form $du/dy = h'(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is going to be quite light on rigor. Since the question is about thought process and mental model, the answer is in a similar vein.

The partial derivative is, intuitively, much like pretending that the function is only a function of one variable, and then taking the derivative with respect to that variable. This means that given values for the variables the function depends on the partial derivative gives you the slope of the function in the direction of the variable with respect to which it was taken.

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}u(x,y) = 0$ states that the partial derivative of $u(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ is zero for all $x$ and $y$. This means that at any particular $y$ changing $x$ does not change the value of the function.
So the function is constant with respect to $x$ at all $x$ and $y$ thus it doesn't depend on $x$.

For a single variable example, $f(x) = 5$ doesn't really depend on $x$ because changing $x$ doesn't change the result of the function.

One motivation for this thought is that one wants to be able to talk about two related functions, say $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x,x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1})=x^2$ and observe that those extra variables in the second one only really matter if you need a function that takes a lot of arguments for some reason (say you need something with a domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$), and that otherwise they are basically the same function. While its all well and good to assert that the second function is a function of $n$ variables, it really only cares about one of them. The people who made the language of Partial Differential Equations decided to refer to this by saying that $g$ only depends on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You are considering a (sufficiently smooth) function $$u:\quad\Omega\to{\mathbb R},\qquad (x,y)\mapsto u(x,y)$$ which a priori could depend on $x$ and $y$ in an arbitrary way. Within the given mathematical situation you then prove that this function in fact satisfies the PDE ${\partial u\over\partial x}\equiv0$, and you are asking yourself: What does this PDE tell me about the function $u\,$?

Consider a horizontal segment $$\sigma:=\{(x,y_0)\>|\> a<x<b\}\ \subset\Omega\ .$$ The auxiliary function
$$\phi(x):=u(x,y_0)\qquad(a<x<b)$$
of one variable $x$ satisfies $$\phi'(x)={\partial u\over\partial x}(x,y_0)\equiv0\qquad(a<x<b)\ ,$$
hence is constant on $\sigma$. We can therefore  say that  along this segment $\sigma$  the value of $u$ depends only on the chosen $y_0$. Since this is true for any horizontal segment $\sigma\subset\Omega$ it is then often said that $u$ "depends only on $y\,$", or that $u$ is "independent of $x\,$". But you have to be cautious: Let $\Omega$ be the plane with the positive $y$-axis removed, and put
$$u(x,y):=\cases{0&$(y\leq0)$\cr y^2\>{\rm sgn}(x)\ &$(y>0)$\cr}\qquad\qquad\bigl((x,y)\in\Omega\bigr)\ .$$
This $u$ satisfies the PDE ${\partial u\over\partial x}\equiv0$ on $\Omega$, but the value $u(x,y)$ is **not** "independent of $x\,$".